# Stylecop Checkin Policy VS2012, TFS2010

Tags: tfs, stylecop

We have StyleCop as part of the project and every time we compile, Stylecop is checking the code. But we already have 100K+ lines of code and it only grows every day. So rebuild of the solution is taking longer and longer than 20 seconds already. I think that the worst part of it is Stylecop.

So we are thinking of the way to remove StyleCop from compilation process, but have it as check-in policy for TFS. I have found 2 projects: [SourceAnalysysPolicy](https://sourceanalysispolicy.codeplex.com/) and [StyleCopPolicy](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/StyleCopPolicy). But neither seem to support VS2012 and numerous posts online suggest they do not work in VS2012.

I can slap StyleCop as a step into our build server (TeamCity), but then we'll have a lot of false failed builds - not really a solution.

I was hoping to have to force all check-ins in TFS to be gated check-ins and run stylecop there via MSBuild script: if no violations - actually check-in and pass control over to TeamCity. If there are violations - warn the developer and not check-in. But I've no idea if that is possible in TFS2010  and how to implement it.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What if you only run `StyleCop` for release builds by adding something like this: `<Import Project="StyleCop.targets" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' " />`

Comment: That's an idea, but I can see people still checking in without building it for release. Might as well right-click on solution and run stylecop on it. I wanted to minimise manual interaction if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an older post but I just released a check-in policy for Visual Studio 2013. I don't know if you already using VS2013 but take a look at this extension. If you want VS2012 support, you can add an issue. If there are enough votes I will add support for it.
https://stylecopcheckinpolicy.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's nice! thanks for letting me know. We are moving to VS2013 and this will be handy!

Comment: Your welcome! I just released it so I hope there aren't much bugs. We are now using it internally for a week now and for so far no bugs :-).

Comment: tried it for couple days in the office. Works fine for us. Extra kudos for the release!

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this problem, we have Stylecop sitting on the build server and checking the rules on every check-in. We initially did have a lot of failed builds because of the stylecop rules, but after a while everybody learned all the rules and got used it. And last 2 months we had no failed builds because of Stylecop. So it all the matter of discipline.